# jquery hiding element using mouseenter / mouseleave

Tags: jquery, hide, mouseenter, mouseleave

So I have two buttons when I move the mouse over them I want a panel to pop out and stay open, however, if the mouse enters another button the panel will close and the panel corresponding to the new button will open.  However, this approach is not very efficient since if I mouse over a button and skip the panel and go somewhere else the panel will stay open.
My solution was to create a div behind the buttons, I wanted my jquery to close any open panels when the mouse moves outside the panels or a button.  However, for whatever reason, the 
$('#Container').hover(function() below does not work.  Any suggestions?

code below, project link: http://jsfiddle.net/max0626/727qp/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.panel1').hide();
    $('.panel2').hide();
    $('#Button1').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.panel2').hide();
        $('#Button2').removeClass('active');
        $('.panel1').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#Button1').addClass('active');
        });
    $('.panel1').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.panel1').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#Button1').removeClass('active');
    });

$('#Button2').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.panel1').hide();
    $('#Button1').removeClass('active');
    $('.panel2').fadeIn("slow");
    $('#Button2').addClass('active');
    });
    $('.panel2').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.panel2').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#Button2').removeClass('active');
    });

$('#Container').hover(function() {
    $('.panel1').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.panel2').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#Button1').removeClass('active');
    $('#Button2').removeClass('active');
    });


});
```

Comment: Code is working as expected for me.

Comment: Same for me. Can you explain better the problem (if there's one)?

Comment: the problem is that if I hover the mouse outside button2 or button 1 after the panel has been open the panel stays open.  If I don't hover on the panel before going somewhere else besides a button the panel won't close.

Comment: see this link  http://jsfiddle.net/727qp/6/. is this you need

Comment: If any issue then ping me back!!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is missing a close div for the container. Code seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#Container').hover(function(e) { 
    if( e.target !== this ) 
        return false;
    $('.panel1').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.panel2').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#Button1').removeClass('active');
    $('#Button2').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick note, to make your code a little easier.. give elements that are related to a "step" the same class. For example, Button2 and panel2 can have the same class "step2".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.step1, .step2').hide();

  $('#Button1').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.step2').hide().removeClass('active');
    $('.step1').fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
  });

  $('.step1').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.step1').fadeOut("fast").removeClass('active');
  });

  $('#Button2').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.step1').hide().removeClass('active');
    $('.step2').fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
  });

  $('.step2').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.step2').fadeOut("fast").removeClass('active');
  });

  $('#Container').hover(function() {
    $('.step1, .step2').fadeOut('fast').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Having said that, it sounds like maybe to fix your actual question, you need to setup a sort of global reset. So anytime you hover anything, you init your reset THEN check for what needs to be visible:

```
$('#button1, #button2).mouseenter(function(ev) {
  $('.step1, .step2').hide().removeClass('active');

  if ($(ev.currentTarget).hasClass('step1')) {
    doStuffForStep1();
  } else {
    doStuffForStep2();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/727qp/9/

```
    $('#Container').mousemove(function(e) {
        if(e.target.id=='Container'){
            $('.panel1').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.panel2').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#Button1').removeClass('active');
            $('#Button2').removeClass('active');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected. But you can reduce your code and make it more generic in following way, so that if you change number of buttons / panels then you don't have to modify your jQuery script.

Add button id as class to panel div like this :

```
<div id="Container">
 <div id="Button1">Button1</div>
 <div id="Button2">Button2</div>
 <div class="panel1 Button1">
     <p>Insert Content Here! for Button1</p>
 </div>
 <div class="panel2 Button2">
      <p>Insert Content Here! for Button2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And use below jQuery : here I have used start with selector of jQuery. Please see document link provided at the bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[class^=panel]').hide();// hide all panels
    $('[id^=Button]').mouseenter(function() {
        hideAndInactive();// hide panel and remove active class from button 
        // fadeIn panel with class = button id        
        $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).fadeIn("slow");
        // add active class to button
        $(this).addClass('active');
     });

     $('[class^=panel]').mouseleave(function() {
        //fadeout current panel
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
        // get class of panel which is same as button id
        var buttonClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];      
        // find previous button with id=buttonClass 
        $(this).prev('[id^='+buttonClass+']').removeClass('active');
      });

    $('#Container').hover(function() {
        // hide panel and remove active class from button
        $('[class^=panel]').fadeOut('fast');        
        $('[id^=Button]').removeClass('active');
     });

    // hide panel and remove active class from button
    hideAndInactive = function(){
       $('[class^=panel]').hide();
       $('[id^=Button]').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/727qp/8/)**

API Doc for [Start with Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)